# Distinguish an explicitly nullable string type in C#

Tags: c#

There are a lot of examples of string properties with "nullable" vs "non-nullable" declarations:

```
public MyClass {
    public string NotNullable {get;set;}
    public string? Nullable {get;set;}
}
```

This is even shown in the [Microsoft C# official documentation on nullables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types) as the primary example of nullable types.

This is made confusing by the fact that strings in C# can be null by default.

```
string myString = null; //100% valid, compile-able code
```

I have a script where I'm checking the types of properties in a class, to see if they are nullable. It's a long story why, but these nullable flags are put in a list and exported.

```
bool nullable = false;
if (classProperty.PropertyType.IsGenericType 
   && classProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
{
    nullable = true;
}
```

This works for `int?`s, class references, `DateTime?` objects, basically anything other than `string?`, it can determine if it's an explicitly-declared nullable property or not.

Is there any way to determine if a property is `string` versus `string?`, and if not, why have (and laud in the documentation) a nullable string type for C#?

---

**Also tried**

An alternate method, comparing the `PropertyType` to a type derived directly:

```
modelProperty.PropertyType == typeof(int) //works
modelProperty.PropertyType == typeof(int?) //works
modelProperty.PropertyType == typeof(double) //works
modelProperty.PropertyType == typeof(double?) //works
modelProperty.PropertyType == typeof(string) //works
modelProperty.PropertyType == typeof(string?) //NOPE!
```

C# vomits an error about not being able to use the typeof operator on a nullable type when passed `string?` despite having literally just done so without issue for `int?` and `double?`. Also, `modelProperty == typeof(string)` is true whether the property was declared with either `string` or `string?`.

Comment: Not a full answer, but int is a value type.  DateTime is a struct.  string is special, it's a reference type to an immutable value.  You also can't have a nullable class reference, like `public Nullable<MyClass> myClass {get;set;}`.  The ? syntax works differently for value types and reference types.

Comment: After looking into the IL code a little, it appears that the compiler doesn't interpret `string?` as a `Nullable<string>`, but rather it treats it as a normal `string`  with a `NullableAttribute` on the property/field and a `NullableContextAttribute` on the getter and setter. Both attributes take a parameter of `2` which signifies nullable. `1` would signify non-nullable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Jesse got me pointed in the right direction. If anyone comes looking later, this is how I ended up checking and it seems to be working across the board:

```
if(modelProperty.PropertyType == typeof(string)
&& modelProperty.GetMethod?.CustomAttributes.Where(x => x.AttributeType.Name == "NullableContextAttribute").Count() == 0){
    nullable = true;
}
```

Still glad to entertain any more succinct answers!